# Why does the content version insert fail in a test?

Tags: apex, callout, failing-tests, contentversion

I have a method that

1. takes a contentVersion where the data is stored locally and
2. does a callout to transfer it to sharepoint
3. creates a new ContentVersion with a link to the sharepoint file to replace the old one with
4. deletes the old version

This works fine when triggered from the ui.

The unit test for the method

1. creates a content version
2. registers the callout mock
3. calls the method
4. checks for the new version

In this case the insert of the content version at 3 fails with Invalid Cross Reference ID [] (no id given in message)

the contentversion to be inserted only has 2 ids, FirstPublishLocationId and ExternalDataSourceId, and I've added asserts assuring they exist directly before inserting the conten version in 3.

Running the test as anonymous apex works fine. So there seems to be some difference in environment in a test.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's going to be difficult to give you an answer. I've created content versions in plenty of unit tests without any problems. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code, using the `{}` format button to make the code more legible.